# Google Maps Geocoding OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geocoding

I'm using `Google Maps Geocoding` on a homepage to type in users address. And I also wrote a `jQuery` script to trigger a submit button by hitting enter key. So I got this code for `Geocoding`:

```
function getValue(){
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode(
        {'address': address},
        function(results, status){
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            }

            else
            {
                alert("An unknown error occured. Refresh the page or contact the IT team!" + status);
            }
    });
}
```

And I got this for trigger the submit button:

```
function triggerButton(){
    $('#address').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $("#submit").click();
        }
    });
}
```

It works nearly fine but it has one error. If I click on submit with my mouse, there is no error. But if I hit enter to click submit there comes an error: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. I found out that this error means that I'm over my quota. But I don't know what this exactly means or how I can fix this. I found many threads but no thread with the same problem I have.

Can someone please give me a hint?

Cheers

**EDIT:** The `triggerButton` function is load on `onkeypress` in the textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" onkeypress="triggerButton()" />
```

Comment: "The triggerButton function is load on onkeypress" What does mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

`<input type="text" id="address" name="address"" />`

JS:

```
function triggerButton(e){    
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $("#submit").click();
        }    
}

$('#address').keypress(triggerButton);
```

BTW, you could use keyup event instead of keypress

Comment: Not sure what you are doing exactly, is event (keypress for #address) not fired or what? How do you call getValue()?

Comment: Oh I noticed your edit. The `(e)` was missing. I add it now and it works fine. Thank you :)